# Why isn't my .net destructor called in this very simple scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, destructor, finalizer

I've got the following code :

```
 public class A
    {
        ~A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("destructor");
        }
    }

 public static A Aref;
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Aref = new A();
        int gen = GC.GetGeneration(Aref);
        Aref = null;
        GC.Collect(gen, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        Console.WriteLine("GC done");

    }
```

I thought my Finalizer method would be called upon my call to GC.Collect, which is not the case.

Can anyone explain me why ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finalizers aren't called before `GC.Collect()` returns. The finalizers are run in a separate thread - you can wait for them by calling `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`.

Answer (score 6):

The finalizer is not called during the collection in your example, cause it is still being rooted by the finalizable queue. It is however scheduled for finalization, which means that it will be collected during the next garbage collection.

If you want to make sure instances of types with a finalizer are collected you need to do two collections like this.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

But generally you should not call the `Collect()` method yourself.

Comment: Why is the second collect needed?

Comment: To collect whatever objects were made eligible by running their finalizers. The a type has a finalizer the instances will be rooted by the finalizer queue until the finalizer has run or been suppressed.

Answer (score -2):

Even if you ask for the GC to collect, it is unsure that this specific object will be destroyed (as it could not be in the generation being collected at that moment)

Comment: In this simple example the OP makes sure that relevant generation is collected. So unless there's a collection before the explicit call to Collect() it should work as expected.