# Usercontrols are created dynamically in run-time, but It has memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

My Application's designed by MVVM.

Main window is MainWindow.xaml as below. Main Window has two usercontrols.

By the way, usercontrol is created dynamically in run-time, when property of viewmodel is changed.
But it seems my application has memory leak.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="InstanceTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InstanceTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="UD1">
        <ContentControl>
            <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="UD2">
        <ContentControl>
            <local:UserControl2></local:UserControl2>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="contentsTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource UD1}" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource UD2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="30" Command="{Binding ChangeViewCommand}">ChangeView</Button>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentsTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

> **MainWindow.xaml is related to MainWindowViewModel.cs.** 
>   According to ViewType property, each usercontrol is created dynamically in run time.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private string viewType;
    public string ViewType
    {
        get { return viewType; }
        set 
        {
            viewType = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ViewType);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ChangeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeView);
    }

    public ICommand ChangeViewCommand { get; private set; }
    private void ChangeView(object o)
    {
        int aa = 1000;
        while (aa > 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

            if (ViewType == "1")
                ViewType = "2";
            else
                ViewType = "1";
            aa--;

            //GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

> **UserControl1.xaml**

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:uc1ViewModel x:Key="uc1ViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource uc1ViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding TextExample}"></TextBlock>
        <Image Source="/InstanceTest;component/Images/sample.jpg" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

> **UserControl1.xaml has uc1ViewModel.cs. UserControl2.xaml has uc2ViewModel.cs as below.**

```
public class uc1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string textExample;
    public string TextExample
    {
        get { return textExample; }
        set
        {
            textExample = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TextExample);
        }
    }

    public uc1ViewModel()
    {
        TextExample = "UD1...";
    }

    ~uc1ViewModel()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Call Destructor");
    }

}
```

> 

ChangeView Function of MainViewModel.cs changes ViewType property every second.
When changing property of ViewType, ui1ViewModel is created as new instance. If ui1ViewModel's instance is created for the next time, I expect old instance of ui1ViewModel is removed by garbage collector.

But, it looks like application has memory leak when testing for bunch of times.
I checked destructor of ui1ViewModel 
and type Debug.WriteLine("Call Destructor") at destructor. but it dosen't call every times. 
When I call GC.Collect() by force, destructor of ui1ViewModel is called and reduce memory size of application.

So, my question is

**Can I call GC.collect() by force in this case? or do you have other way to solve this problem?**

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606524/why-isnt-my-net-destructor-called-in-this-very-simple-scenario

Comment: As DataContext="{StaticResource uc1ViewModel}", uc1ViewModel is allocated every time. So do I have to call GC.Collect() not to have memory leak?

Comment: No, as a matter of fact, there is no way where calling GC.Collect manually will ever prevent a memoryLeak. Please read the link provided in my last comment. You most likely dont have a memory leak. If you are affraid you have one, then profile your memory consumption for a long time

Comment: The reason I'm afraid of memory leak is I already tested for a long time. Memory of application start from 25M. Except manually GC.Collect(), the memory is up to 35M. I already looked up the program with Windbg and profiler to find cause.

Comment: @Dianinwater - There is absolutely no reason to assume you have a memory leak when only rising to 35 MB on windows! the GC reserves chunks of memory when it deems nessesary. These chunks can easility outgrow 10 mb!

Comment: http://www.diaonwater.com/attachment/1018254979.zip 

This source is I made situation occur memory leak.

Comment: Why I concerned about that is actually real application increase memory highly(for example up to 200M after performing 100 times,). so that's why I made the sample to show you. So I assume the program will be exhausted.

Comment: @Dianwater - I've checked your sample and there is no memory leak whatsoever. Know that the GC RESERVCES memory as it seems fit. This depends on your system configuration, available memory, memory usage etc. seeying 200+ mb for reserved memory is not strange at all under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a memory leak either:

> A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever
>   run.

Raymond Chen has a nice explanation on what people wrongly understand by Garbage Collection:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx

I'll always remember this:

> Garbage collection is simulating a computer with an infinite amount of
>   memory. The rest is mechanism.